# How do you use wget to download most up to date file on a site?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep, wget

Hello I am trying to use wget to download the most update to day McAfee patch and I am having issues singling out the .tar file. This is what I have:

```
wget -q -O - ftp://ftp.mcafee.com/pub/antivirus/datfiles/4.x/ | grep -o -m 2 "avvdat-[^\']*"
```

However when I run the above command it gives me:

```
avvdat-8065.tar">avvdat-8065.tar</a>  (95191040 bytes)
avvdat-8066.tar">avvdat-8066.tar</a>  (95385600 bytes)
```

When I need it to just be the most recent.tar file in between the `<a> </a>` which in this case would be avvdat-8066.tar. Can someone please help me out with greping the correct .tar I am not too good with regex or sed.

Comment: All I get when I run that command is: `avvdat-8066.tar">avvdat-8066.tar</a>  (95385600 bytes)`  As a matter of fact, looking at it through `ftp` only the `avvdat-8066.tar` is in that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
wget $(wget -q -O - ftp://ftp.mcafee.com/pub/antivirus/datfiles/4.x/ | grep -Eo "ftp://[^\"\]+" | sort | tail -n1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest modifying your grep regex so it retrieves only the file name, then using sort to sort the results and tail to discard all but the last one.

```
wget -q -O - ftp://ftp.mcafee.com/pub/antivirus/datfiles/4.x/ | grep -o -m 2 "avvdat-[^\'\"]*" | sort | tail -1
```